# Display all data in Django to external js

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I've been using an `id` to get all data from external js but the question is I want to display data from the database, but using the template is on external js, I just call an 'id' from external js to my HTML, is somebody know how to read `{for data`} under external js? It is very helpful for me if someone give some idea about my problem.

**views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
   tasks = task.objects.all()
   tasks = {'requestsdata':tasks}
   return render(request, 'dashboard.html',tasks)
```

**dashboard.html** - I've been using id to fetch all data inside external js

```
<div class="card-body">                   
    <div id="demo2"></div>
</div>
```

**custom.js**  External js

```
{% for listofdata in requestsdata%}
var kanban2 = new jKanban({
element: '#demo2',
 gutter: '15px',
 click: function (el) {
   alert(el.innerHTML);
 },
 boards: [{
  'id': '_todo',
  'title': 'To Do (Item only in Working)',
  'class': 'bg-info',
  'dragTo': ['_working'],
  'item': [{
      'title': `
            <a class="kanban-box" href="#"><span class="date">24/7/20</span><span class="badge badge-info f-right">medium</span>
            <h6>{{listofdata .description}}</h6>   
            //etc. so on .........
       `,
    }
  ]
},
]
});
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can someone know how to deal with this problem I'm out of option pls

Comment: Is anyone know this?